# How do i change database name in Laravel?? I already changed database in config/database.php and .env

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

How to change database name in Laravel? 
I already made changes in config/database.php and .env file. I need database name as scoolmgmt
Config/database.php

```
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'scoolmgmt'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

```
**Routes.php**
Route::get('/dbname', function(){
    return DB::getDatabaseName();
});
```

Output is:- laravel

Comment: I want a database name scoolmgmt

Comment: What is configured in the `.env` file for the `DB_CONNECTION` and `DB_DATABASE ` keys ?

Comment: configured in the .env file:
```DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=scoolmgmt
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: are you running this using artisan serve ? do you have any caching on ?

Comment: yes @Mike Caching is on.

Comment: Caching stores your config files. clear the cache and try again

Comment: how do i clear cache? of that

Answer (score 3):

Caching stores the configured values from the config files.
You can clear the **Cache** with the following artisan command `php artisan config:clear`

After your change you can make a new cache file with the command `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: php artisan cache:clear
By this it was cleared.
and got the desired output. of database

Comment: @OmkarKumbhar If this worked for you please consider marking this answer as accepted. so other people that experience the same problem can quickly find an answer. This is of course up to you.

Answer (score 0):

type in project terminal

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Your database will definitely get updated